# Django cannot locate a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make a customer and employee login and register page...however whenever I try to go to localhost:8000/customer register, I get a page not found error not found error. this is my

urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('customer_resgister', views.customer_register.as_view(), name = 'customer_register'),

]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .models import User, Customer, Employee
from .forms import CustomerSignupForm, EmployeeSignupForm


# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html')

class customer_register(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = CustomerSignupForm
    template_name = 'accounts/customer_register.html'

#def customer_register(request):
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    Phone_no = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 150)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    Phone_no = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Customer, Employee, User
from django import forms

class CustomerSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    phone_no = forms.CharField(required = True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def data_save(self):
        user = super().save(commit = False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.save()
        customer = Customer.objects.create(user = user)
        customer.phone_no = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_no')
        customer.save()
        return user


class EmployeeSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    designation = forms.CharField(required = True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def data_save(self):
        user = super().save(commit = False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.save()
        employee = Employee.objects.create(user = user)
        employee.phone_no = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_no')
        employee.designation = self.cleaned_data.get('designation')
        customer.save()
        return user
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'apk-h*1!*f-=^6zw^_q0q!z6att9f+exfr+k(!awfvybu^x(l%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo_register.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demo_register.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

All my templates are stored in accounts/templates/accounts

I don't know what am I doing wrong here...please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the issue is with your templates. A 404 error shows when the url cannot map to the correct view.
You can share the error page snippet and you can also try and add a slash to your url path for customer_register

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo in the third path in url_patterns, it should be register instead of 'resgister'.
2. Use space instead of underscore

   url_patterns = [
   path('customer register', views.customer_register.as_view(), name = 'customer_register')
   ]